# container_fs_ metrics are coming zero for all pods in prometheus operator

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, cadvisor

I am using stable/prometheus-operator for monitoring kubernetes cluster. 
But the disk metrics are showing zero for all the pods. Is there anything to be done to resolve this.
cadvisor end point is active in prometheus

[image: image for prometheus screenshot]

Service monitor configuration

```html
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2019-10-24T06:40:18Z'
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: prometheus-operator-kubelet
    chart: prometheus-operator-6.18.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubelet
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: '2595'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/default/servicemonitors/prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubelet
  uid: 5039932b-3224-4c24-ae13-d9a2b540c02b
spec:
  endpoints:
    - bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      honorLabels: true
      port: https-metrics
      scheme: https
      tlsConfig:
        caFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecureSkipVerify: true
    - bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      honorLabels: true
      path: /metrics/cadvisor
      port: https-metrics
      scheme: https
      tlsConfig:
        caFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecureSkipVerify: true
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - kube-system
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubelet
```

Comment: Add prometheus config file or service monitor yaml to the question body

Comment: attached the service monitor yml.

Comment: Can you check if your cadvisor pod is working correctly?